# Boot Camp can't see new internal SSD

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, ssd

I have a 15-" MacBook Pro Retina from mid-2014 which came with a 250-GB SSD (which I will henceforth refer to as "the old SSD"). I've bought a [1-TB Aura SSD](http://www.owcshop.eu/catalog/product_info.php/aura-macbook-mid2013-till-2015-p-1376#.WPbeyBgXlL9) (which I will henceforth refer to as "the new SSD") and installed it. I've also restored/migrated my stuff from TimeMachine and downloaded the driver that OWC provides in order to make the new SSD compatible with Boot Camp.

I now want to make a partition on the new SSD to install Windows 10. I've been told I need to use Boot Camp because Disk Utility (which I've used before to partition and erase discs) can't make a bootable partition for Windows. (If this is incorrect, I'd much rather use Disk Utility than Boot Camp, but in what follows I'll assume it is true.) (Mind you, I've never used Boot Camp before, so please bear with me if I'm doing things wrong.)

My problem is that Boot Camp can't see the new SSD, only my external drives. I've tried restarting from the old SSD (which now lives inside a USB case and can thus be connected to my Mac as an external drive), but that doesn't help.

Here are two screenshots of the Boot Camp window (sorry, I've got three things showing there and only two can be seen at a time):

[image] [image]

The SeaGate drive is an external drive I use to store stuff that doesn't fit in my internal SSD; I don't want Boot Camp to touch that. "Mac HD" is the old SSD. I'm not sure what "OWC Envoy Media" is, but googling it returns images of the old SSD's new case, so I'm guessing it's also the old SSD.

Thanks in advance for any help. :)

Comment: Please open Terminal.app, enter `diskutil list` and `sudo gpt -r show disk0`, copy the output in the Terminal window and add it to your question. **Don't post this as comment!** Also (your link > Specs): *4. Use of Windows on the Aura SSD requires direct installation of Windows to the drive. OS X's Boot Camp utility is not supported.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot Camp wants to create a media with Windows drivers for installation later in the process (where you may not be able to reach Windows Update for drivers), and the images you show is where to store them.  Not where to install Windows.

This is described in the Boot Camp instructions that you were urged to print out and follow carefully very early in the process.  You may want to restart the process and do this.

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot. I didn't really know what I was doing. I don't recall ever seeing those instructions, but searching online did the trick. :)